# Regular expression with look around and substitution

Tags: python, regex

I'm successfully using Python to substitute text within tags, e.g. `<tag>some text here</tag>`, using the regex `([a-zA-Z\s]*)`, but when simplifying the regex to `(.*)` it fails. See example below

```py
import re

text = """<tag>
    abc
    def
    ghi
</tag>
"""

print("\nSubstitute the text within the tags , i.e. <tag>...</tag>, with jkl\n")

print("1. Substitution works")
x = re.sub(r'(?<=<tag>\n)([a-zA-Z\s]*)(?=\n</tag>)',r"    jkl",text,re.DOTALL)
print(x)

print("2. Substitution fails")
y = re.sub(r'(?<=<tag>\n)(.*)(?=\n</tag>)',r"    jkl",text,re.DOTALL)
print(y)
```

The output is

```
Substitute the text within the tags , i.e. <tag>...</tag>, with jkl

1. Substitution works
<tag>
    jkl
</tag>

2. Substitution fails
<tag>
    abc
    def
    ghi
</tag>
```

After reading the documentation I still can't still figure out why. If anyone can help shed some light on this Python regex behavior, i.e. why `([a-zA-Z\s]*)` works and `(.*)` fails, it wold be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone seems to have missed this: The documentation for `re.sub` show the parameters as:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

That is, the fourth parameter is the count of the number of replacements to be done, not the flags to be used. You said `re.DOTALL`, but it was being interpreted as the `count` parameter. You simply needed to have said `flags=re.DOTALL` to ensure that the correct flags were being used so that the `.` character would match a newline:

```
y = re.sub(r'(?<=<tag>\n)(.*)(?=\n</tag>)',r"    jkl",text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

You should update all of your code to add `flags=` before `re.DOTALL`.

```
import re

text = """<tag>
    abc
    def
    ghi
</tag>
"""
print("2. Substitution works!")
y = re.sub(r'(?<=<tag>\n)(.*)(?=\n</tag>)',r"    jkl",text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(y)
```

Prints:

```
2. Substitution works!
<tag>
    jkl
</tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\s` in the first one matches any whitespace character (ie the line break).

The `.` does not match line terminators.

https://regex101.com/ is a very useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

[image: find explanation here]

Please find the answer on the attached screenshot from regex101.com